# GoodPractice: class inheritance with... inheritable scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I'm sure what I'm looking for as already been discussed somewhere, but I can't find it.
I was wondering what are the usual best practices around the system I'd like to build :

Let's say I have a base class with a data container (ScriptableObject in unity, but could be generalized to C# with a standard class):

```
public class Employee: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected EmployeeSO _employeeSO;

    // ...
}
public class EmployeeSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public string employeeName;
}
```

Now, let's suppose I'd like to inherit from the Employee to create a Manager with a few more rights :

```
public class Manager: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected ManagerSO _managerSO;

    // ...
}
public class ManagerSO : EmployeeSO
{
    public string role;
}
```

Having ManagerSO inherit from EmployeeSO makes sense IMO - All the data about a particular manager would be inside the same ScriptableObject container.

However, I still have the reference to _employeeSO, which is misleading and error-prone.

What would be the correct way of doing such inheritance if I want to keep the actual data separated ?

Answer (score 0):

So I know nothing of Unity and it's `serialization` system but in C# generics are the way to go:

```
public class Employee<T>: MonoBehaviour where T: class
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected T _scriptableObject;
}

public class Employee: Employee<EmployeeSO> {
}

public class Manager: Employee<ManagerSO > {
}
```

Comment: Why not `where T : EmployeeSO` ? In general so far generics where not serialized by Unity .. in later versions this was added so it depends on which version OP is using

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics

```cs
public abstract class Person<T> : MonoBehaviour
    where T : EmployeeSO
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected T _personSO;

    // ...
}

public class Employee : Person<EmployeeSO>
{
}

public class Manager : Person<ManagerSO>
{
}
```